# Create anchor href with javascript and not have host url in link

Tags: javascript, url, anchor, href

I am attempting to create a link dynamically using javascript, but the host url is prepended to the link every time. How do I stop this from happening. I created an example on js fiddle. the link created prepends "http://fiddle.jshell.net/mTgtr/show/" to the www.google.com link.

http://jsfiddle.net/mTgtr/

```
var eventLink = "www.google.com";
var elEventBlock = document.createElement('div');
var elA = document.createElement('a');
elA.setAttribute('href', eventLink);
elA.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
elA.innerHTML = "test";
document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(elA);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should prefix the URL with the protocol, such as `http://`, `https://`, `ftp://`, etc.

Comment: To further elaborate: there are two types of link on a webpage, absolute and relative. Any link that doesn't begin with a protocol such as http:// or https:// will be treated as relative, and the browser will attempt to navigate to that link as if it is a directory or file contained in the current directory, i.e. `http://mysite.com/directory_containing_link/www.google.com`. To navigate to a different website, you must include the protocol so that the browser knows to treat the link as absolute.

Comment: @Grant Thanks that works perfectly! I probably should have known that already, and maybe did at some point.